# how can i fix this c code / BLAS error?

Tags: c, r, blas

I'm trying to write a c function(that later will be used in R scripts) that uses BLAS lib from R

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>

void foo(int *dimension, double *vect1, double *vect2)
{
    const int dim = dimension[0];
    const int incxy = 1;

    //swaps two vectors
    F77_NAME(dswap)(&dim,vect1,&incxy,vect2,&incxy);
}
```

I compile the code using :

```
R CMD SHLIB foo.c
```

I get the error :

```
foo.o:foo.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `dswap_'
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 3):

Including a header file is not the same as linking a library.

I don't actually know anything about R, but I did some searching and found http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects which indicates you need the BLAS_LIBS variable - if you're not using a makefile it looks like you can just get the output of the command "R CMD config BLAS_LIBS" and then include the output on the command line. You might also be able to just add it to the PKG_LIBS variable, but I don't know enough about R to be sure.

EDIT:

> have set file Makevars.win to include

```
PKG_LIBS=$(BLAS_LIBS) 
PKG_LIBS=$(LAPAK_LIBS)
```

That *replaces* the PKG_LIBS variable with LAPAK_LIBS. Try it with += instead of =.

Comment: Your point is generally true but with R, the libR.so shared library is typically linked against libblas and BLAS symbols should therefore be visible.  See my answer for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

have set file 
Makevars.win to include

```
PKG_LIBS=$(BLAS_LIBS) 
PKG_LIBS=$(LAPAK_LIBS)
```

but error persists.

BINGO : added to

```
"R CMD SHLIB foo.c"
```

the output from

```
"R CMD config BLAS_LIBS"
```

as in

```
"R CMD SHLIB foo.c -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.2/bin/i386 -lRblas"
```

and now it works.

Comment: Don't add an aswer, rather edit your own question.  Also, your want `PKG_LIB+=...` as the `=` simply overwrites.

Comment: From '[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)' section 1.2, rather than adding to the command line, add a file Makevars with `PKG_LIBS+=$(BLAS_LIBS) $(LAPACK_LIBS)`.

Comment: will try tomorow ... now i must sleep

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be linked to whatever provides the `dswap` function.  I would guess that's in the R library.

Comment: R_ext/BLAS.h is dswap's header file

Comment: @user605507: Including the header is not the same as linking against a library.

Answer (score 0):

It works here (and please ignore that my `~/.R/Makevars` selects a particular `CC` and `CFLAGS`; and also ignore minor whitespace edits):

```
edd@max:/tmp$ R CMD SHLIB foo.c
gcc-4.5 -I/usr/share/R/include -fpic -O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 \
        -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -shared -o foo.so foo.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
edd@max:/tmp$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>

void foo(int *dimension, double *vect1, double *vect2)
{
    const int dim = dimension[0];
    const int incxy = 1;

    //swaps two vectors
    F77_NAME(dswap)(&dim,vect1,&incxy,vect2,&incxy);
}
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Ubuntu 10.10, stock packages for R, gcc etc.  Maybe your R is locally built in a static library configuration?

Comment: I am coding on windows. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Maybe. You could try to be more explicit -- try settings PKG_LIBS accordingly, or experiment first by copying the command R CMD SHLIBS shows you and add -L and -l switches as needed.